# How to add pattern to input in contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have this code in contact form 7:
[text* name placeholder  "Name *" ]
I want this input accept only caracter
Any help please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using custom code :**

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function alphanumeric_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

if ( 'name' == $tag->name ) {
$name_of_the_input = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? trim( $_POST['name'] ) : '';

if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/',$name_of_the_input) ) {
$result->invalidate( $tag, "Allowed characters only" );
}
}

return $result;
}
```

**Validation using plugin :**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: you can use a plugin

Comment: Thank you so much 
You helped me a lot